# pg_basebackup is taking too long

Tags: postgresql, backup

I am trying to setup streaming replication on Linux. `pg_basebackup` is failing due to huge data size i.e 7TB. It's failing because it's taking too long to backup i.e. 20 hrs. and the required WAL file is already gone from the master. So how do I fix this issue and how do I speed up the `pg_basebackup` process? I am using PostgreSQL 13. What do I need to change in the `postgres.conf` of master or slave, and what switches do I need to use to speed up the backup process? I am using the following command

```
pg_basebackup -h 192.168.100.81 -U repuser -p 5432 -D /var/lib/postgresql/13/main \
 -Fp -Xs -P -R -C -S Secondary01 --checkpoint=fast --max-rate=1024M
```

Comment: What make you think this is a configuration problem?

Comment: Since you specify `-C` along with `-S`, you probably hit the `max_slot_wal_keep_size` configuration option. Check if you have this limit enabled. Otherwise, postgresql will never delete the old WAL, even when a DBMS stopped due to lack of free space.

Comment: I though about configuration issues because there is nothing much I can do/control from pg_basebackup utility. I am already using best available switches. Thanks

Comment: What is the bottleneck?  Getting the data from the disk on the sending end, across the network, or onto the disk on the receiving end?  You ask about the slave configuration, but you are creating the slave, it doesn't yet exist and so doesn't have a configuration, right?

Comment: And the hardware involved, @amanullah, have you thought about that?  The network?  What environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Melkij has suggested, the use of a slot *should* prevent the needed WAL from being removed.  However, I suspect there is some timing bug in pg_basebackup which allows it to happen anyway.  I've see it a few times "in the wild" but have never been able to get it when I was trying to, which makes it hard to investigate and solve.

If you fell afoul of max_slot_wal_keep_size as Melkij thinks, I think it would have failed with a different error message `pg_basebackup: error: unexpected termination of replication stream: FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command`, which is why I think it is more likely you have hit the timing bug.  When I have hit this bug, I got the error message very soon after the backup has started.  But it is easy to miss this message, and then it proceeds to copy the entire data directory anyway, only to finally fail hard at the very end.

So one option is try again, keeping an eye for error messages at the start so you can manually abort the process, rather than letting it run for 20 useless hours.

While pg_basebackup is certainly convenient, it is not very good in several ways.  So you might want to do an exclusive backup using a different method to copy the data, such as `rsync`.  The compression option for pg_basebackup is kind of useless, it transfers data over the network in its uncompressed glory, and then compresses it on the client side.  This is the opposite of what you want to stand up a replica.  The -z option for rsync will compress data for transit, then uncompress it once it arrives.  How beneficial this will be will depend on your data, but I've seen it improve transfer speed over a slow network by 15 fold.

Another advantage of an exclusive backup is that if it gets interrupted by a network glitch or something, you might be able to get rsync to pick up where it left off using the -c option, while pg_basebackup won't do that.  But how efficient this will be will depend on how much of your data has turned over in the mean time.

Of course you will have to start out with WAL archiving turned on, or use pg_receivewal or something like that, to capture the WAL generated during the initial copy, as rsync won't do it for you the way that pg_basebackup tries to.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @jjanes. So if, I don't want to turn on archiving and go for pg_receivewal, then what would be my steps in order to mimic streaming replication on secondary as an alternative.